# Configuring cordova-plugin-firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap

I have installed cordova-plugin-firebase.
In the root folder of my app I have zipped www folder, config.xml, google-services.json and GoogleService-Info.plist.
I use this file in phonegap build and it builds fine for ios. 
I have installed the app in a iPhone 7, but when I run the app it crashes.

In the plugin page I can read (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase#important-notes):

> "IMPORTANT NOTES
>
> This plugin uses a hook (after prepare) that copies the configuration
>   files to the right place, namely platforms/ios/\/Resources for ios and platforms/android for android.
>
> Firebase SDK requires the configuration files to be present and valid,
>   otherwise your app will crash on boot or Firebase features won't work.
>
> PhoneGap Build
>
> Hooks does not work with PhoneGap Build. This means you will have to
>   manually make sure the configuration files are included. One way to do
>   that is to make a private fork of this plugin and replace the
>   placeholder config files (see src/ios and src/android) with your
>   actual ones, as well as hard coding your app id and api key in
>   plugin.xml."

So I think what is happening is that GoogleService-Info.plist and google-services.json are not placed in the right place.

But, how can I fix this? I don't understand the solution about making a private fork?!?

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Someone using this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself.

Because of hooks doesn't work in phonegap build I have installed Xcode and Android Studio.
Now the plugin is working in android, but not ios.
I will post a question for this.